# WP_Query sometimes returns zero results when there are matching posts - why?

Tags: wordpress

This one has got me stumped.

I have a category.php file which contains this loop:

```
<?php
if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <div class="entry-content description clearfix">
            <h2 class="category-subtitle"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            <?php echo the_content(); ?>
            <?php global $withcomments; $withcomments = 1;
    ?>
        </div><!-- .entry-content -->
    <?php
    endwhile;
else :
    get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );
endif;
?>
```

This block of code works fine and always returns the results one would expect.

In addition, outside the loop (after it, in case that matters), I've got a column to one side with this loop - I'm going to refer to this as the newsfeed loop for the sake of clarity:

```
<h3 class="newsfeed-heading"><a href="/category/news/">Latest News</a></h3>
<?php
    // wp_reset_query(); * Same results with or without wp_reset_query
    $args = array(
    'cat' => 89,
    'order'   => 'ASC'
    );
    $custom_query = new WP_Query($args);
    //echo "<h2>Found: $custom_query->found_posts</h2>";
    while($custom_query->have_posts()) : $custom_query->the_post();
?>
    <div <?php post_class(); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
        <h4 class="highlight1"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
        <p><?php $content = get_the_content(); echo mb_strimwidth($content, 0, 160, '...');?></p><div class="morelink"><a title="<?php the_title(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a></div>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; 
  // wp_reset_postdata();  * Same results with or without wp_reset_postdata
?>
```

Now, in the majority of cases, these two loops play nicely together and both loops return the set of results I'd expect. But not always.

As far as I can tell, I think if the main category loop only contains one result, then the newsfeed loop is always correct. But if the main category loop has multiple posts in the results set, the newsfeed loop frequently works fine. So I have not been able to spot a pattern.

I have tried putting `wp_reset_query();` in different places, clutching at straws, but it doesn't make any difference.

Incidentally, when the newsfeed loop works, it always returns the correct results set. But when it doesn't, it always returns nothing and `$custom_query->found_posts` returns zero.

I would really appreciate some advice on where to look for a possible solution.

Comment: Edited to show that I have explored the need or otherwise for wp_reset_postdata and wp_reset_query()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

I was convinced that the problem wasn't in the code and I should have worked this out sooner.

The problem was caused by a Wordpress plugin called ReOrder Post Within Categories https://wordpress.org/plugins/reorder-post-within-categories/

This plugin allows you to manually reorder selected Categories via a drag-and-drop interface in the Dashboard.

This explains why the custom query worked most of the time - only about ten of the 80+ Categories was being manually re-ordered and of course those are the ones that cause the conflict with my WP_Query.

I'm not in a position to start hacking at the plugin so the workaround is to disable the plugin and reorder posts by altering the publication dates instead.

Thank you to the contributors who attempted to answer this question for me.

Answer (score 10):

For anyone searching, `found_posts` **returns 0** if arguments is using `'no_found_rows' => true`.

Answer (score 4):

You are missing `wp_reset_postdata();` after your custom query. As soon as you call `the_post()`, you are setting the `$post` global to the value of the current post. This is true for the main query and any custom instance of `WP_Query`. In `get_posts`, this happens when you call `setup_postdata()`.

As already pointed out, `wp_reset_query()` is used with `query_posts` which you should **never** use as it breaks the main query object and anything that relies on the main query object like related posts, pagination and page functionality.

If the above does not work, look for any `posts_**` filters or any instance of `pre_get_posts` that is poorly written in your theme or a plugin. Apart from these suggestions, your code should work.

Comment: Is `wp_reset_postdata()` really necessary, since this second loop is occurring outside of / after the default loop? I was under the impression that this was only necessary for nested loops.

Comment: Yes, it is, remember, any custom query which uses `the_post()` or `setup_postdata` sets the `$post` global to that current custom query's post. Not resetting this does cause unexpected results.

Comment: Inserting wp_reset_postdata() before running the custom query doesn't make any dfifference to the end result. The custom query still returns a results set sometimes and no results at other times. And I still can't see a pattern.

You're correct, of course, wp_reset_query() is not needed before  the custom query. Again, however, removing it does not affect the output. 

I completely removed anything from functions.php which used pre_get_posts or posts_** and it didn't make any difference to this problem.

Comment: `wp_reset_postdata`should go after the custom query, not before

Comment: Sorry, Peter, I did put the reset after the query. Out of desperation I even tried it both before and after! But what I should have thought of sooner was disabling Plugins one by one to see if any of them were causing a conflict.

Answer (score 0):

I had experienced a similar problem. Finally as recommended, removed

`'no_found_rows' => true,`

however, it doesn't work.
So I have rearranged the query args

`'posts_per_page' => 10,`

The post_per_page at the end of the query args results in "0" found_posts. Later shifted to the top of the query args, the query results in the actual result like "100" found_post.

Answer (score 0):

The issue I faced on my side was that the query was retrieving private custom post types. This will require the logged in user to have the correct priviledges to get access to the posts. Therefore you need to ensure that you're using a user with the right roles and when using a api ensure that the nonce key is passed.

Answer (score -2):

If anyone comes here looking for an answer and none of the other solutions work. I was able to make this work by add `wp_die();` right before the end of my function call.